# MongoDB: Adding field to array field object based on a field value within object

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb-query, pymongo

I need help mongoDB query. Here is my collection.
Play list in mongodb

```
 JukeBox Collection
{
[
roomName : 'room1',
playlist :

[{ Filename: 'file1.mp3',
   Filekeywords: 'party music, couples'
},
{ Filename: 'file2.mp3',
  Filekeywords: 'fine dining, family , kids'
},
{ Filename: 'file1.mp3',
  Filekeywords: 'elderly, family'
}]
},
roomName : 'room2',
playlist : [{
...
}...
]
}
```

My need is to insert a field to one object of the array field "PlayPosition: 15 #seconds" if the filename matches the specified one in the object field. The expected collection after updating:

```
JukeBox Collection
{
[
roomName : 'room1',
playlist :

[{ Filename: 'file1.mp3',
   Filekeywords: 'party music, couples',

},
{ 
   Filename: 'file2.mp3',
   Filekeywords: 'fine dining, family,kids'   
   PlayPosition: 15 #seconds
},
{ Filename: 'file1.mp3',
  Filekeywords: 'elderly, family', 

}]
```

I want to traverse the array field, find the matching field (file name) and then insert the 'PlayPosition' key+value if it does not exist. If it exists, it should update that field. My assumption is that I need to use update_one, I should use "$addToSet" to achieve this. My utility function is as below :

```
UpdateCurrentPlayStatus(filename = "file2.mp3", position_in_seconds=15):

   #What should be my query?
   JukeBoxUpdate( {roomName: 'room1'}, 
    { 
        "$addToSet":{ 
            "playlist.$": {
                 "Filename": filename,#file2.mp3 . Does this filter 
                 "PlayPosition": position_in_seconds
                 }
        }
    }
```

It gives me the following exception: **pymongo.errors.WriteError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.**

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the query. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the query working like this.

```
JukeBox.update_one( {roomName: 'room1', "playlist":{"$elemMatch":{"Filename": filename}} }, 
    { 
        "$set":{ 
            "LessonList.$.PlayPosition": position_in_seconds
            }

    }
```

This works even if the field does not exist. If it exists, it overwrites the existing field value.
Point to note is - if I want to create any query filter involving the elements of the array field, $elemMatch is necessary in the filter part of the update.

Besides, I experimented with"$addToSet" instead of "$set". It creates array of values under the field.

```
PlayPosition: 15  #with "$set"

PlayPosition: #with "$addToSet"
[15]
```